# How to handle new tab vs new window in selenium webdriver in multiple browsers

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, firefox, webdriver

I have a bit of code that goes through a help menu on a site i am testing and selects a few elements to interact with.  However if I run the code in Firefox, the elements open up in a new window.  If I run the code in Chrome, the elements open up in a new tab.  I can handle either or but I don't know how to handle both.

I tried to change the profile of Firefox to ONLY use new tabs but no matter what I set preferences to in code or just using a new profile via ProfileInt, Firefox always uses new windows regardless.

Is there a sure fire way programmatically to force firefox to open only tabs every time for a new link or chrome to always use a new window?  So far all my research has given me nothing.

Comment: I suppose you could load a plugin in your profile that either forces all new tabs to open in a new window (if you want to use the chrome default), or opens all new windows in a new tab (if you want to use the firefox default). There are tons of plugins on either browsers plugin marketplace to choose from probably.

Comment: I didnt think about plugins.  I'll certainly look into it.